# acquire/release memory ordering example

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, atomic

I don't understand this sample from [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/AtomicSync) :

" Assuming 'x' and 'y' are initially 0:

```
-Thread 1-
 y.store (20, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 2-
 x.store (10, memory_order_release);

 -Thread 3-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 20 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0)

 -Thread 4-
 assert (y.load (memory_order_acquire) == 0 && x.load (memory_order_acquire) == 10)
```

Both of these asserts can pass since there is no ordering imposed between the stores in thread 1 and thread 2.

If this example were written using the sequentially consistent model, then one of the stores must happen-before the other (although the order isn't determined until run-time), the values are synchronized between threads, and if one assert passes, the other assert must therefore fail. "

Why in `acquire/release` two assert can pass?

Comment: Provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org)!

Comment: @Oswald - in this case, the pseudo-code is sufficient. It's how this kind of low-level stuff is typically described and analyzed. An SCCE wouldn't help, because running it wouldn't tell you anything useful: it might or might not show differences in ordering, depending on the system and fine details of timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your memory model is not sequentially consistent, then different threads can see a different state of the world, and in such a way that there is no single, global state (or sequence of states) that is consistent with what both thread see.

In the example, thread 3 could see the world as follows:

```
x = 0
y = 0
y = 20    // x still 0
```

And thread 4 could see the world as follows:

```
x = 0
y = 0
x = 10    // y still 0
```

There is no global sequence of state changes of the world that is compatible with both those views at once, but that's exactly what's allowed if the memory model is not sequentially consistent.

(In fact, the example doesn't contain anything that demonstrates the affirmative ordering guarantees provided by release/acquire. So there's a lot more to this than what is captured here, but it's a good, simple demonstration of the complexities of relaxed memory orders.)

Comment: I am still confused. memory ordering is for ordering non-atomic or other atomic operation around one tagged atomic operation. How it can be possible atomic load of one atomic variable can't see atomic store of same variable in another thread? Why when Th3 see `y = 20` Th4 can't see `y = 20`?

Comment: @MohammadRB: Because every thread lives in world of its own. In Th3 the store has happened, and in Th4 it hasn't. That's what it means to not have consistency.

Comment: Whenever i think that i understand memory ordering, i see an example that afraid me. it seems that i am a lazy student that even a good teacher like you can't teach me ;) i can't realize how it can happen.

Comment: @MohammadRB: It seems that your brain is hardwired to sequential consistency. Try to forget everything and just imagine that every thread lives in a world completely of its own, unconnected to any other world. The only connections between worlds are synchronization points.